# Bitfield and union for low level data structures and type conversion in Rust

Tags: casting, rust, unions

I need to manage bitfield data and unions. Here is the code like I think it in C:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)){
    union {
        struct __attribute__((__packed__)){
            unsigned short protocol : 4;
            unsigned short target : 12;
            unsigned short target_mode : 4;
            unsigned short source : 12;
            unsigned char cmd;
            unsigned char size;
        };
        unsigned char unmap[6]; // Unmapped form.
    };
}header_t;
```

I use this union to switch easily from a mapped to an unmapped form. I can write to `header_t.protocol` or `header_t.source` and get it back as an `u8` array using `header_t.unmap`. This switch uses no time and shares the same memory block.

I tried to do the same thing in Rust but I didn't find a clean way to do it. I succeeded in making it using two structures and a dedicated `impl` to switch between them:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
pub struct Header {
    protocol:    u8,  // 4 bits used
    target:      u16, // 12 bits used
    target_mode: u8,  // 4 bits used
    source:      u16, // 12 bits used
    cmd:         u8,  // 8 bits used
    size:        u8,  // 8 bits used
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub struct UnmapHeader{
    tab:[u8; 6],
}

impl Header {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub fn unmap(&self) -> UnmapHeader {
        let mut unmap_header = UnmapHeader { tab: [0; 6],};
        unmap_header.tab[0] = (self.protocol & 0b0000_1111) | (self.target << 4) as u8;
        unmap_header.tab[1] = (self.target >> 4) as u8;
        unmap_header.tab[2] = ((self.target_mode as u8) & 0b0000_1111) | (self.source << 4) as u8;
        unmap_header.tab[3] = (self.source >> 4) as u8;
        unmap_header.tab[4] = self.cmd;
        unmap_header.tab[5] = self.size;
        unmap_header
    }
}

impl UnmapHeader {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub fn map(&self) -> Header {
        Header{
        protocol: self.tab[0] & 0b0000_1111,
        target: ((self.tab[0] & 0b1111_0000) >> 4) as u16 & (self.tab[1] << 4) as u16,
        target_mode: self.tab[2] & 0b0000_1111,
        source: ((self.tab[2] & 0b1111_0000) >> 4) as u16 & (self.tab[3] << 4) as u16,
        cmd: self.tab[4],
        size: self.tab[5],
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn switch() {
    let header = Header {
        protocol: 0b0000_1000,
        target: 0b0000_0100_0000_0001,
        target_mode: 0b0000_0100,
        source: 0b0000_0100_0000_0001,
        cmd: 0xAA,
        size: 10,
    };
    let unmap_header = header.unmap();
    assert_eq!(unmap_header.tab[0], 0b0001_1000);
    assert_eq!(unmap_header.tab[1], 0b0100_0000);
    assert_eq!(unmap_header.tab[2], 0b0001_0100);
    assert_eq!(unmap_header.tab[3], 0b0100_0000);
    assert_eq!(unmap_header.tab[4], 0xAA);
    assert_eq!(unmap_header.tab[5], 10);
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic Rust solution?

Comment: If this type of dense packing is necessary, then perhaps the better approach is to just store the data as `[u8; 6]`. Then create accessor functions which read and write to the bit positions. For example: `get_protocol` and `set_protocol`.

Comment: Do you need a FFI betwen Rust and C that passes bitfields around, or do you just wish to use bitfields within Rust?

Comment: I don't need/want to use C, I just need to understand the best rust way to do  something similar.

Comment: For bitfield I also try to use [this bitfield crate](https://crates.io/crates/bitfield), but that just create getter and setter as @PeterHall solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust (since quite recently) [supports C-style unions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1444-union.md). However, unions require an `unsafe` block and are not idiomatic for pure Rust code if you don't have to interact with C unions.

One approach is to model your underlying data just as a `[u8; 6]` and then provide more friendly accessor functions:

```
pub struct Header {
    tab: [u8; 6],
}

impl Header {
    pub fn get_protocol(&self) -> u8 {
        self.tab[0] & 0b0000_1111
    }

    pub fn set_protocol(&mut self, value: u8) {
        self.tab[0] = self.tab[0] & 0b1111_0000 | value & 0b0000_1111;
    }

    // etc..
}
```

As you mentioned in one of the question comments, you can keep the code simpler by using the [bitfield](https://crates.io/crates/bitfield) crate.

Another approach could be to define your struct with the individual fields, but convert to `[u8; 6]`. As you have presented it though, the fields take up more space than the `[u8; 6]`, so there isn't a convenient conversion (e.g. unsafe `std::mem::transmute`) without having to shift around the bits for each individual field anyway. So probably the solution above is better.

Regardless of the underlying representation, defining friendly accessors is probably a good idea in this situation. It's a cost-free abstraction, which will let you change your mind about the representation later without having to change how it is used.

Comment: To keep others values on your set_protocol function you should add some masks `self.tab[0] = (self.tab[0] & 0b1111_0000) | (value & 0b0000_1111);`

Comment: @NicolasRabault Yes, true!