# Keep two 7 bit structs in a byte wide enum

Tags: rust, byte

I have two structs, which both only need 7 bits to represent themselves:

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
struct TypeFlags(u8);

// TypeFlags has capabilities that are invalid for Control
impl std::ops::BitOr for TypeFlags {
    type Output = Self;

    fn bitor(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self(self.0 | rhs.0)
    }
}

#[repr(transparent)]
struct Control(u8);
```

Since both types only need 7 bits, an "Either" type could be created which only occupies one byte.

```
// problem: the compiler sets aside
// a "flag" byte for the enum variant.
// size = 2
enum Either {
    Type(TypeFlags),
    Ctrl(Control)
}

// problem: pattern matching is painful
struct PackedEither(u8);
```

Are there any sub-byte optimizations for enum that I can take advantage of, or will I have to manually implement the bit flag on a struct like `PackedEither`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitfield and union for low level data structures and type conversion in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602853/bitfield-and-union-for-low-level-data-structures-and-type-conversion-in-rust)

Comment: As an aside, unless you're working on embedded or working on performance critical software (and this is from somehow who's done/does both). Then honestly, spending so much mental energy shaving off a single byte is highly likely _not_ going to gain you any measurable performance gain in the long run

Comment: @IłyaBursov No. I'll edit my question to reflect why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is not able to make that optimization, but for the sake of argument let's assume the compiler were to make it and lets say `TypeFlags` gets stored as `0b0xxx_xxxx` and `Control` as `0b1xxx_xxx`.

Now here is the problem:
In Rust we can match on a reference to `Either` and get references to the contained values:

```
fn unwrap_control_ref(either: &Either) -> &Control {
    let Either::Ctrl(control) = either else {
        panic!("was not a `Either::Ctrl`");
    };
    control
}
```

Now the compiler would have to produce code, that references a value of `Control` but, it does not store that anywhere in memory it only stores a "`Control | 0b1000_0000`".

Sadly even if we were to use standard library internal attributes to programatically change the range of `TypeFlags` to `0..128` and `Control` to `128..256`, it still [does not use the nieche like we want and optimize to a single byte](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=8580cff38fb9584a14d6141c3ccc090c).